# gvim editor -- E488 Trailing characters after search and replace questions

Tags: regular-expression, gvim

I have the following search and replace expression where I am trying to format a document in a single step using multiple commands separated by **`|`**

```
:%s/\s\{6}...\d\d\s/  /g | %s/\(.*Inlet.*\|.*AIR.*\)/\0 false | %s/\(===)/\0 #
```

I know the problem is that the interpreter does not understand that after the word "false" it needs to start with the next command.

I have tried using parenthesis and different delimiters, but it does not work.

Comment: don't you just need a `/` after the false?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `:substitute` is

```
:[range]substitute/pattern/replacement/[flags]
```

(Although `/` can actually be any character, which is helpful for when the pattern contains slashes.)

Notice that the delimiter after `replacement` is *not* optional.

Comment: *"delimiter after replacement is not optional."* Well, in many cases it *is* optional. It's not optional when the command is followed by something else, in which case Vim needs it to know where the replacement ends... But if you don't have anything following it (a `:s` flag such as `/g`, or another command following a `|` separator), then you can just end the line and Vim will know the replacement ends there... Right?

Comment: I think in the case of hitting enter at the command line, pr terminating the command in vimscript with a newline, you might be ok @filbranden. In sed it’s never optional :P